# Dibujar poligono y punto

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy calculando la distancia entre un punto y un polygono

```
from shapely import wkt

polys = ('POLYGON((-58.612406970999984 -34.55196600599993, -58.61272573499997 -34.552244351999946, -58.611851334999983 -34.552907077999976, -58.611473561999958 -34.552566878999983, -58.612331868999945 -34.55191298799997, -58.612406970999984 -34.55196600599993))')
point = ('POINT(-53.6461527438567 -26.2619788971019)')
poly.distance(pt)
poly.boundary.distance(pt)  
poly.exterior.distance(pt)
```

Como puedo representar el polygono y el punto graficamente, o sea dibujarlo y que esa representacion verifique si el resultado del codigo anterior es la distancia correcta.

Comment: [Aquí hay algo relacionado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10984080/8933039) es una información que podría ayudarte (Traducela a español)

Comment: [Aqui hay algo interesante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23414895/8933039)

Comment: muchas gracias estoy revisando la informacion que me pasastes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No me queda claro de que manera la representación gráfica pueda confirmarte que la distancia es la correcta, de cualquier forma, graficar el polígono y el punto de puede resolver de la siguiente forma:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.wkt import loads as load_wkt

# Cargamos los objetos
poly = load_wkt('POLYGON((-58.612406970999984 -34.55196600599993, -58.61272573499997 -34.552244351999946, -58.611851334999983 -34.552907077999976, -58.611473561999958 -34.552566878999983, -58.612331868999945 -34.55191298799997, -58.612406970999984 -34.55196600599993))')
point = load_wkt('POINT(-58.612915127438567 -34.5522788971019)')

# Dibujamos el punto
plt.plot(point.x, point.y,  marker='o', markersize=3, color="red")

# Dibujamos el polygono
x,y = poly.exterior.xy
plt.plot(x, y, color='#6699cc', alpha=0.7, linewidth=3, solid_capstyle='round', zorder=2)
plt.show()
```

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comentarios:

- Tuve que modificar las coordenadas de tú ejemplo, del punto ya que se encontraba demasiado lejos del polygono por lo que todo se veía demasiado pequeño como para notar que era cada cosa
- Use `load_wkt()` para cargar las definiciones ["Well Known Text"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well_Known_Text)

Comment: Era lo que necesitaba